# How do I set up an asp.net mvc app with Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

I plan to have 2 projects.
1. mbtech.crm.mvc
2. mbtech.crm.tests

I will have a solution named mbtech.crm

What is the best way to set these up so that I can track them in Subversion?

Option 1 (then where does my solution file go)?
- mbtech.crm.mvc
    - tags
    - trunk
    - branches
- mbtech.crm.tests
    - tags
    - trunk
    - branches

Option 2
- mbtech.crm
    - trunk
            mbtech.crm.sln
        - mbtech.crm.mvc
        - mbtech.crm.tests
    - tags
    - branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 would be my choice, they're two parts of the same solution, so it doesn't make much sense to separate them.  I can't see any reason why you'd branch your code but not  your tests, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If the projects are strong related, then you should probably use the same trunk.
If they are independent of each other, or have just a shallow relationship, then you would probably be better of with different trunks.